# Strip Trademark Symbol from string Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to prep some data for a designer. I'm pulling data out of SQL Server with python  on a Windows machine (not sure if OS is important). How would I make the string 'Official Trademark™' = 'Official Trademark'? Also, any further information/reading on unicode or the pertinent subject matter would help me become a little more independent. Thanks for any help!

Edited:

Perhaps I should have included some code. I'm now getting this error during run time: 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 2:ordinal not in range(128).' Here is my code:

```
row.note = 'TM™ Data\n'
t = row.note
t = t.rstrip(os.linesep).lstrip(os.linesep)
t = t.replace(u"\u2122",'')
```

Comment: Blender and others have the answer, so here's some reading about how unicode is represented in python: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trademark symbol is Unicode character `U+2122`, or in Python notation `u"\u2122"`.

Just do a search and replace:

```
'string'.replace(u"\u2122", '')
```

Comment: The " (gotta be careful with that Unicode, as you must .decode() it when printing)" part is misleading, you only have to *encode* yourself when Python thinks your terminal only supports ascii. I think for some reason on Windows it does.

Comment: When you print unicode Python automatically encodes it with the encoding given by `sys.stdout.encoding`. If your terminal is set up properly then that should be UTF-8 or whatever encoding makes sense for your language. Otherwise the encoding defaults to ascii and printing non-ascii characters will fail.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> 'Official Trademark™'.strip('™')
'Official Trademark'
>>>
```

Comment: You can't use non-ascii characters in Python source code: http://codepad.org/ymgtruH9

Comment: You can, you just have to make `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` the first line in your source file: http://codepad.org/BYIPuDox

Comment: In Python 3, the declaration is not required any more. In Python 2, you should use unicode strings, `u'™'`.

Comment: I put `#coding: utf-8` as the second line of the script (the first being the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`) and it works too.